# How to compute this contour integral with a modulus sign in the integrand,

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Evaluate the integral $$∫_{∣z∣=ρ} \frac {1}{|z−a|^{2}}|dz|$$ where ρ is a positive number, a is a complex number, and |a|<ρ.

I welcome any hints on how to get started on this problem.

The modulus sign is tripping me up a bit -- Cauchy's integral formula doesn't seem applicable either.

I then expanded the modulus function in the denominator to get

$$\sqrt {(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2}$$

and expanding the terms inside the square root just makes things messier and doesn't lead to anything insightful.

Another idea would be to use the Residue Theorem, since the integrand is real-valued, but what can I do about the |dz| term?  And also, the integration appears to be over a circle and not a subset of the real line.  Usually, applications of the Residue Theorem is to compute real integrals over R or $R^+$ and then we complexify the integral and choose a suitable contour to give some easy estimates of the integrand over certain parts of the contour.  Here, a complex contour is already given in the problem statement:  |z|=$\rho$

Thanks,

Comment: what do you mean by $|dz|$ as a measure of the integral?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest, @hamedp.  I'm just transcribing this (old) exam question onto this question post.  But if I had to guess and just go strictly by definition, |dz| should be square root of (dx)^2 + (idy)^2.  But, I wouldn't know how to start with such an integrand...hmm...

Comment: Why don't you simply parametrize the integral as $z=\rho e^{it}$. Then if it really is $|dz|$ we have $|dz| = \rho dt$, the limits of the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the denominator $(a^2 + \rho^2 - 2a\rho\cos t)$. This is a doable real integral. You don't need any fancy complex analysis to do this integral actually.

Comment: ...paremetrizing did not even cross my mind.  I am foolish.  I get so narrowly focused on trying to apply the Residue Theorem, when I see complex integration problems.  Thanks so much for the hint, @hamedp.  I will proceed now.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Hi @hamedp, can I ask you a quick follow-up question?  When I write out my integrand as f(z(t)*z'(t)dt, should I put the z'(t) factor in modulus, like |z'(t)|?  I notice that some definitions from various online sources do this, but some other sources do not.  Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I see you have already addressed this  specifically for this problem statement, but what about in general?  Why do some sources put the z'(t) factor in modulus, while some sources do not? Thanks @hamedp

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the integrand, e.g., depending on whether it is a line integral of a vector field or a scalar-valued function?  Thanks @hamedp

Comment: can you give me link for that online source you mentioned which uses absolute value?

Comment: Hi @hamedp, here is one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral.  For the line integral of scalar fields, this Wiki page puts the z'(t) factor in absolute value, while it does *not* do this for the line integral of vector fields and for the complex line integral (see a little bit further down on that page).  Thanks,

Comment: In this case, the line integral is over measure $ds$ which is already an absolute value, so you have $ds = |\vec{r}'|dt$. In general it depends on what type of measure you have.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for your time @hamedp - have a great night :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437103/how-do-i-solve-this-complex-integration-problem

Comment: Thanks so much for the link @RonGordon.  I had just finished solving this problem in the same way, too.  Knowing to rewrite |dz| was tricky and awkward, especially when it is tempting to go to a Riemann integral, thinking that the solution is easier at that stage (it sure wasn't for this problem), so I'm happy to see another example of this question type through your solution :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Along the curve
$$\gamma:\quad\phi\mapsto z(\phi):=\rho e^{i\phi}\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq2\pi)$$
one has
$$|z-a|^2=(z-a)(\bar z-\bar a)=(z-a)\left({\rho^2\over z}-\bar a\right)$$
and $dz = i \rho e^{i\phi} d\phi$. The latter implies
$$|dz|=\rho d\phi={\rho\over i}{dz\over z}\ .$$
In this way we obtain
$$Q:=\int_\gamma{|dz|\over |z-a|^2}={\rho\over i}\int_\gamma{1\over(z-a)\left({\rho^2\over z}-\bar a\right)}\>{dz\over z}={\rho\over i}\int_\gamma{1\over(z-a)(\rho^2-\bar az)}\>dz\ .$$
Since $|a|<\rho$ we therefore get
$$Q={\rho\over i}\>2\pi i\>{\rm res}\left({1\over(z-a)(\rho^2-\bar az)}\biggm| z:=a\right)={2\pi\rho\over \rho^2-|a|^2}\ .$$

Comment: Thanks so much @ChristianBlatter :-)

Comment: How this comes : $$|dz|=\rho d\phi={\rho\over i}{dz\over z}\ $$

Comment: Because, $$|dz|=|i \rho e^{i\phi} d\phi|=\rho|d\phi|$$